# E404 Not Found When Publishing New NPM Package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to publish a new npm package called nibble-qmk-hid. I've created the project via `npm init`. I've logged into npm via `npm login`, and then when I try to publish the package via `npm publish --access public`, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/nibble-qmk-hid
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'nibble-qmk-hid@1.0.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-23T17_47_29_933Z-debug.log
```

I've also tried updating npm to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

Once plausible explanation might be that you need to [have an npm account](https://www.npmjs.com/signup) and be signed in. Try this before you publish:

```sh
npm login
```

Failing that, try the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-unscaoped-public-packages)

Comment: I was able to log in successfully, but my account says it is not activated. I'm currently logged on in the npm web interface.